# Параметризированные типы и мой пример

Tags: java, массивы, generics

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] iArray = {11, 22, 33, 44, 55};
        String[] sArray = {"Mike", "Soffie", "Flippy", "Digital"};

        print(iArray);
        print(sArray);
    }

    public static <Integer> void print(Integer[] array) {
        for (Integer x : array) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Я не пойму почему при вызове метода print куда мы ложим sArray строковый массив, когда в самом методе указано, что он будет принимать Integer массив, а не строковый, он всё равно отрабатывает (строковый).

Ведь если мы сделаем так:

```java
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);
list.add(4);
```

То если мы введем `list.add("Hello")`, то у нас сразу подчеркнет и скажет мол тут `Integer`, а не `String`, так же и в моём примере я хочу понять, почему компилятор не ругается

Comment: уберите <Integer> и всё будет нормально, работать не будет)

Comment: @Serodv так, а почему строковый массив принимает метод print, когда я четко указал в параметры только Integer, как такое возможно вообще?

Comment: <Integer> - это ваш кастомный тип, который имеет такое же название, как и java.lang.Integer и "затеняет" его в дженерик методе. В вашем случае это может быть любой тип. Напишите ради примера <Integer extends String> и проанализируйте, что происходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В коде вашего метода

```
  public static <Integer> void print(Integer[] array){
    for(Integer x: array){
      System.out.println(x);
    }
  }
```

словом `Integer` обозначен не стандартный `java.lang.Integer`, а тип-параметр. Такому параметру можно дать любое имя, точно так же, как параметру метода можно дать имя существующей вне этого метода переменной:

```
  int myName; 
  void myMethod(double myName) {
    System.out.println(myName) 
  }
```

В вашем примере параметр назван `Integer`, видимо, специально, чтобы вас запутать. С таким же успехом метод может быть записан как

```
  public static <T> void print(T[] array){
    for(T x: array){
      System.out.println(x);
    }
  }
```

по смыслу это абсолютно идентичная запись. Такая запись просто означает, что в качестве параметра это метод может получать массив объектов любого типа, а в цикле `for` выбирает из массива объекты этого же типа и передает их в качестве параметра методу `System.out.println()`. Таким образом, этому методу можно передавать и `Integer[]`, и `String[]`, и `Object[]` -- любые массивы с элементами объектных типов.

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае идет речь не о классе `Integer`, а об универсальном типе с названием `<Integer>`. Для наглядности, код лучше переписать так:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] iArray = {11, 22, 33, 44, 55};
    String[] sArray = {"Mike", "Soffie", "Flippy", "Digital"};

    print(iArray);
    print(sArray);
}

public static <T> void print(T[] array) {
    for (T x : array) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```